# Local Chart for Teichmuller Space as A Manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces, teichmuller-theory

Let $(R,p_1,…,p_n)$ be a Compact Riemann surface of genus $g$ with $n$ marked points. Its deformation space is $H^1(R, K_R^{-1}\otimes\mathcal{O}(-p_1),…,\mathcal{O}(-p_n))$. From Riemann-Roch theorem, it is of dimension $3g-3+n$. Choose $v_1,…v_{3g-3+n}$ supporting away from $p_j, j=1,…n$, which are  representatives of a basis of $H^1(R, K_R^{-1}\otimes\mathcal{O}(-p_1),…,\mathcal{O}(-p_n))$. By solving Beltrami equation $$\bar{\partial}f=s_1v_1+…+s_{3g-3+n}v_{3g-3+n}\partial f, |s|<1$$, we can get a new compact surface $\Sigma$ with $n$ marked points from quasi conformal map $f:R\to \Sigma$. Scott. Wolpert says it can be a local chart for Teichuller space.

My question is that what kind of manifold will be obtained from the charts constructed above? Analytic manifold or just a smooth manifold?

Comment: What do you mean by *analytic*: Real or complex analytic?

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike: complex analytic, locally the chart is holomorphic to a polydisk in complex Euclidean space.

Comment: You should add this to the question, as well as the precise reference of Wolpert's paper (he wrote many). Technically speaking, the statement is ill-posed since you have to explain how representatives of $H^1$ are chosen: In order to get complex-analyticity you have to use Beltrami differentials depending holomorphically on $R$.